# Given 2 Points of a Rectangle, find the Center?

Tags: geometry

In a feature that I am writing for a program, I need to find the (x, y) of the center of a rectangle while only being provided the (x, y) of the top left and bottom right corners. I've been out of a math course for awhile now and cannot thing of any equations that I can use to solve this. Here is a Paint image I drew up to show what I am working with. Note that the points are going to be dynamic, so the numbers won't ever be the same. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

[image: Center of Rectangle with 2 corners]

Comment: Calculate the coordinates of the middle point between the two points given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the midpoint between the two corners. If the points are
$(p_1,p_2)$ and $(q_1,q_2)$, then the midpoint is $$\left(\tfrac{p_1+q_1}2,\tfrac{p_2+q_2}2\right)$$
the coordinate-wise "average" of the two points.

Comment: I do remember this equation from back in college. I thought I needed something like the Pythagorean Theorem to solve this. Now I feel dumb lol. Thank you!

Comment: Giving this one the answer, because there is more of an explanation, even though Botond answered first.

Comment: Botond's anwer wasn't there when I began composing my answer, so it wasn't first by much. I suppose Botond types faster. ;)

Comment: Ya you guys were about a minute apart.

Answer (score 1):

Take the average of the coordinates.
For your example:
$$\left(\frac{318+482}{2},\frac{164+309}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch!